# C# Excel unable to copy worksheet

Tags: c#, excel

I am working on a web App where user can upload an Excel file and I need to copy data from the user worksheet to a destination worksheet in order to do some calculation. To do so, I have the following code:

```
    public class ExcelCtrl
    {
        private Excel.Application excelApp = null;
        private Excel.Workbook srcworkbook = null;
        private Excel.Workbook destworkbook = null;

public void excel_init(String srcpath, String destpath, string copyrange)
    {
        //Open Excel
        this.excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        //Open user's file
        this.srcworkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(srcpath);
        Excel.Worksheet srcworksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)srcworkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        //Open calculation file
        this.destworkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(destpath);
        Excel.Worksheet destworksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)destworkbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        //Range of copy
        Excel.Range from = srcworksheet.get_Range(copyrange);
        Excel.Range to = destworksheet.get_Range(copyrange);

        //Copy
        from.Copy(to);

        //Close user's file
        srcworkbook.Close();

        //Open Xla file
        excelApp.Workbooks.Open("someXlaFile.xla");
        excelApp.Workbooks.Open("AnotherXlaFile.xla");  
    }
```

Basically I have to different method to run different calculations and they have the following structure. What differ one calculation method to another are just the macro called, the number of macro and the copy range.

```
    public static string Calculation1(String InputFileName, String CurDir)
    {
        //The Excel calculation file and its path
        string filename = "CalculationFile.xls";
        string path_server = ExcelCtrl.DossierCalcs + filename;

        ExcelCtrl excel = new ExcelCtrl();

        excel.excel_init(CurDir + "\\" + InputFileName, ExcelCtrl.DossierCalcs + filename, "A1:Z105");

        //excel.excel_run("Macro1");

        //The rest is not important
        path_server = CurDir + "\\Resultats - " + InputFileName;

        excel.excel_run("AnotherMacro", path_server);

        excel.excel_close();

        return path_server;
     }
```

Now all work fine, except one calculation (the one above). I am unable to copy data from the user worksheet.
I have tested to :

- (normal usage) upload an Excel file with some new data and when I download the file after calculation, it is still the old data.
- reduce the range of copy ( I though maybe it is too big) to "A1:Z50" then "A1:A2". However, I have another calculation file where I copy a range of "A1:M730" and it works fine.
- copy it manually with Ctrl + C; Ctrl + V (I thought maybe the worksheet is protected from modification or something)

With the first 2 tests, I still got old data (not the user data) and the last one works, I can paste user data; though not very useful if someone need to do it manually everytime an user ask for this calculation.
I hope this is enough for you to understand my problem and hope you can guide me.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Hello,
Just to clarify a little bit about what I am doing. I have an web app where user can download an Excel xlsx file and they have to fill in with their data. After that, They have to upload their file to the server and choose the calculation they want to run. On the server side, I copy their data (see code above) to the corresponding Excel calculation file. So for each calculation I have one input file for the user and one calculation file to run. In total I have 14 input files and 14 calculations files and 13 of them work fine.
I have done some more tests, the following tests do not copy my data :
(And I am using Excel 2010)

- Changing the name of my destination Excel file to something more common because there were a "#" in the file name.
- Changing the name of my destination Excel file to one another destination file where the copy works.
- Changing the worksheet color (I really don't believe that will solve my problem but I have nothing to lose)
- Deleting worksheets from my destination file one by one

And the following tests work (data are copied to the destination file) :

- Copying to a new Excel file
- Copying to an other Excel calculation file (let's say file B) where I know the copy works

My thought for the last case is because when I open my problematic Excel file, 2 warnings come up. The first one says that the workbook contains link to other data sources and ask me if I want to update it (even after updating, it keeps asking me everytime I open it) and the second one says that the workbook contains links that can not be updated.I have also this 2 warnings when I open file B but with this file the copy works.
So I have tried to delete all links in the file and it does not work either. Futhermore, those links are used in my 13 others files.
I am kind of lost now since I have deleted all worksheet and links from my Excel file and it still won't copy. The only difference I see between my problematic file and a new file is that the former contain Macro.